# Zscore with Rolling Window Panel Data

Tags: merge, stata

I am trying to calculate the zscore with Rolling window. I need to actually calculate standard deviation for a 3 year rolling window to calculate z-score. A minimal working example is given below:

```
     use http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta
     xtset country year
     rolling sd_x1=r(sd), step(1) window(3) saving(sd_x1, replace) keep(year): sum x1, detail
```

Now after this I need to `merge` it back with the original file. But the variable `year` does not appear but a column name date appears with all missing values. I am trying to `merge` it using the following command:

```
     merge 1:1 country year using sd_x1
```

However, I get the error that variable year is not found and actually this variable is not kept while running the rolling command. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am always surprised that people have interest or faith in standard deviations based on three values.

A more direct approach would be to use `rangestat` (SSC). The syntax could be something like

```
use http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta
xtset country year
rangestat (sd) sd=x1, interval(year 0 2) by(country)
```

except that I cannot test this at the moment.

The key difference here is that `rangestat` produces new variables in the current dataset. Search the Statalist archives for examples of `rangestat` use.

Note that in your example the `detail` option is unnecessary as `summarize` by itself produces standard deviations.

You can extend this approach to get the mean at the same time.